How to Prevent Black Stripe Appearance on Navigation Bar When Scrolling Up?
I'm currently developing an iOS app using SwiftUI and facing an issue with the navigation bar's behavior in a view wrapped in a NavigationStack. Specifically, when I scroll up the list, a black stripe appears at the top, overlaying the navigation bar along with the title causing an undesired visual effect as the large title condenses.
Here's the code snippet demonstrating the setup:
var body: some View {
    if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
        NavigationStack {
            List(filteredChannels, id: \.topic) { item in
                ChatItemChannel(chatChannels: item)
                    .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
                    .listRowBackground(Color.clear)
            }
            .listStyle(.plain)
            .task {
                getTheTopics()
            }
            .navigationTitle("Channels")
            .searchable(text: $searchText)
        }
    }
}

I've attempted to make the navigation bar's background transparent and even tried removing its shadow in hopes of addressing the issue, but the black stripe persists upon scrolling.
My goal is to either completely eliminate this black stripe or customize the navigation bar's appearance so that it aligns with the app's design while retaining the large title display mode.
I would greatly appreciate any suggestions on how to customize or prevent this behavior in SwiftUI. Has anyone else encountered this and found a solution or workaround that allows for more control over the navigation bar's appearance during scrolling?

Can you update the example to show dummy content, so that the problem can be reproduced? I tried it with simple Text items (replacing ChatItemChannel) and don't see an issue. A screenshot to show the stripe would also be helpful.

i tried with a plain text, it acts the same
